# How to handle window based pop up after alert in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver, alerts

After saving user, there are two alerts and one window based pop up is coming. I am able to handle alert but not able to handle window based pop up after the alert in selenium.

I need to click on the button"Ok" for window based pop up after the alert pop up.

```
public void clickonSaveButton() {
    savebutton.click();
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
    Helper.acceptAlert(driver);
    String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); 
    String subWindowHandler = null;
    Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); 
    Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
    }

    driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); 
    System.out.println("Sub window is:" +subWindowHandler);
    driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);
    System.out.println("Parent window is:" + parentWindowHandler);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a new window? how many items `driver.getWindowHandle();` return? and what happened when you tried to click? post the code and explain what exactly is the problem.

Comment: Hi , I have checked my sub window and parent window is returning same data.  Sub window is:CDwindow-CBCA48ED5FEC0A6FAAB74DF00D4CBA7C
Parent window is:CDwindow-CBCA48ED5FEC0A6FAAB74DF00D4CBA7C

Comment: Let me explain the exact scenario:                                                                                There is a button "Add New User" and on clicking on it, pop up window will open and user needs to add all the fields for the user. On clicking on button "Save", there are two alerts coming "Are you sure you want to save details?" and the second alert is "Are you sure you want to save without contact details" After these alerts, one pop up window is coming with two buttons "Ok" and "Add New User", I need to click on "Ok" button but not able to do it,

Comment: You don't have two windows, you have one. Don't use `switchTo().window()`

Comment: ok Sure then how I will click on button "Ok"?

Comment: The same way you click any other button.

Comment: I did it but it is not working

Comment: public void clickonSaveButton()
{
savebutton.click();
  
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
  
  
Helper.acceptAlert(driver);
okbutton.click();

Comment: I have added CSS to locate "Ok" button, but getting below error:                                   unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point (830, 60). Other element would receive the click: 
...
(Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.121) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)

Comment: Hey Thanks for your help, i have done it...